# TCP Spring Integration - Dispatcher has no subscribers for 'response' channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to make TCP call to server by providing some message and getting response back. I prefer to use channel adapter to send and receive bulk messages. The problem I am facing is with the response channel. Getting "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel " for response channel.
Everything is working fine except the response not getting transported on response channel. I can see the handshaking at server and the response in the log being put on the response and logger channels. But after that exception is thrown. Configuration setup is:

```xml
<gateway id="clientPositionsGateway" service-interface="MyGatewayInterface">
        <method name="fetchClientPositions" request-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel" />  
    </gateway>


    <channel id="clientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <splitter input-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel"
            output-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <channel id = "singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <transformer
        input-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel"
        output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel"
        ref="dmPosBaseQueryTransformer" />

    <channel id = "dmQueryRequestChannel">
        <!-- <dispatcher task-executor="executor"/> -->
    </channel>

    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="csClient"
           type="client"
           host="somehost"
           port="12345"
           single-use="true"
           deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
            />

    <ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="dmServerOutboundAdapter"
            channel="dmQueryRequestChannel"
            connection-factory="csClient"
            order="2"
            />

    <ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="dmServerInboundAdapter"
            channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"
            connection-factory="csClient"
            error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<channel id="dmQueryResponseChannel"/>
```

Comment: Show, please, the configuration for **subscriber** to "dmQueryRequestChannel". Try this one `<logging-channel-adapter channel="dmQueryRequestChannel">`

Comment: 17:23:30.347 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Message received [Payload=CLIENT_ID|MANAGER|HOLD_TYPE
AAAIH||CURR
][Headers={timestamp=1379678010347, id=c51a97ab-0fc6-4270-bdda-46a91e0d102e, ip_tcp_remotePort=22010, ip_address=hostaddress, ip_hostname=hostname, ip_connectionId=hostname:22010:93360e5b-82f8-4e06-906a-6a5989d0d583}]
17:23:30.347 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.channel.ExecutorChannel - preSend on channel 'dmQueryResponseChannel', message: [Payload=CLIENT_ID|MANAGER|HOLD_TYPE
AAAIH||CURR

Comment: ][Headers={timestamp=1379678010347, id=c51a97ab-0fc6-4270-bdda-46a91e0d102e, ip_tcp_remotePort=22010, ip_address=hostaddress, ip_hostname=hostname, ip_connectionId=hostname:22010:93360e5b-82f8-4e06-906a-6a5989d0d583}]
17:23:30.347 [executor-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'

Comment: 17:23:30.347 [executor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers][Headers={timestamp=1379678010347, id=5cdcae44-e874-4ad2-af47-4f9b91a8cdde}]
17:23:30.347 [executor-1] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - (inner bean)#2 received message: [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers][Headers={timestamp=1379678010347, id=5cdcae44-e874-4ad2-af47-4f9b91a8cdde}]

Comment: Are you going to answer to my questions? What StackTrace I understand. I mean that there maybe no subscriber of "dmQueryResponseChannel" or it isn't started

Comment: @ Artem Bilan: Tried logging-channel-adapter configuration on response channel and now not getting the exception. But main thread is still executing and not returning to the program segment after gateway call.

Comment: Right, because **logging-channel-adapter** is one-way. And haven't tald anything regarding main gateway who wants to get response. Please, provide more info about your-use case and show more config and I'll show you full-dress answer

Comment: I am sending a message to server which in turn sends back a message and I deserialize and transform response manually. Ive provided full configuration above. Using gateway method which takes collection produce readable message by server.

Comment: @ Artem Bilan: do you require any additional inputs on it?

Comment: First of all: who does handle Message on "dmQueryResponseChannel"? Confirm, please, that your message flow is initiated by request/response gateway.

Comment: Ive configured 'dmQueryResponseChannel' to receive the response and 'tcp-inbound-channel-adapter' uses it for response. should  Gateway not be used with adapter ? thats what you meant to say?

Comment: But it is a channel where inbound adapter **sends** Message after read it it from TCP. From other side there has to be a handler who **receives** that Message from that channels. That's why you get ' Dispatcher has no subscribers'. Gateway is OK, but I should understand the reason do not to use `<tcp:outbound-gateway>`

Comment: there are thousands of clients, each bound to separate request and response, and need to be processed in parallel. Thats why I am using inbound and outbound adapters.

Comment: Even I get same exception when trying to use inbound and outbound gateways.

Answer (score 1):

As Artem said in his comment, 'Dispatcher has no subscribers' means here that there is no endpoint configured to receive the response on `dmQueryResponseChannel`, or the endpoint configured with that channel as its input channel is not started.

In any case, even when you resolve that, using independent adapters for request/response scenarios is tricky because the framework has no way to automatically correlated the response to the request. That's what the outbound gateway is for. You can use collaborating adapters, but you have to deal with the correlation yourself. If you are using a request/reply gateway to initiate the flow, you will have to use a technique such as the one explored in the [tcp-client-server-multiplex sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex). This is because using independent adapters means you'll lose the `replyChannel` header used to get the response back to the gateway.

Or, you can use a void returning gateway to send the request, and an `<int:outbound-channel-adapter/>` so the framework will call back with the response and you can do your own correlation programmatically.

Comment: Even if i am using void returning gateway, messages are not flowing to server. Also, using outbound gateway is throwing same exception. Quiet confused with how to co-relate the response with request channel!!! Am I not using collaborating adapters model?

Comment: You need to show *all* of your configuration upstream and downstream of these components, for example we need to see what endpoint you have the reply channel connected to.

Comment: With that configuration, you have 2 subscribers to `dmQueryResponseChannel`; the transformer and the inbound gateway. After the transformer you have a simple logging adapter. Replies will be round robin distributed messages going the logger will never reach the gateway. However, as I said, this configuration would never work because you can't send arbitrary asynchronous replies (such as received by the inbound adapter) to the gateway reply channel - you have to restore the replyChannel header. Please try again with an outbound gateway and show the new configuration, and show a full log.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration settings:

```
<gateway id="clientPositionsGateway" service-interface="com.example.ClientPositionsGateway">
    <method name="fetchClientPositions" request-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel"  reply-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"/>  
</gateway>

<channel id="clientPositionsRequestChannel" />

<splitter input-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel"
        output-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

<channel id = "singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

<transformer
    input-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel"
    output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel"
    ref="dmPosBaseQueryTransformer" />

<logging-channel-adapter channel="clientBytes2StringChannel"/>  

<channel id = "dmQueryRequestChannel">
     <dispatcher task-executor="executor"/> 
</channel>

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="csClient" 
       type="client" 
       host="serverHost"
       port="22010"
       single-use="true"
       deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
       />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="dmServerOutboundAdapter"
        channel="dmQueryRequestChannel" 
        connection-factory="csClient"
        /> 

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="dmServerInboundAdapter"
        channel="dmQueryResponseChannel" 
        connection-factory="csClient" 
        error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<transformer input-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel" output-channel="clientBytes2StringChannel" ref="dmPOSBaseQueryResponseTransformer"
        />

<channel id="dmQueryResponseChannel"/>

<channel id="clientBytes2StringChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ClientPositionsGateway {

    String fetchClientPositions(List<String> clientList); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain why this might work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that solved my Problem :

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/clientGIM2Position.xml"})
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

    public class GetClientPositionsTest {

    @Autowired

    ClientPositionsGateway clientPositionsGateway;

    @Test

    public void testGetPositions() throws Exception {

    String positions = clientPositionsGateway.fetchClientPositions(clientList);

    System.out.println("returned !!!!" + positions);

           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <!-- intercept and log every message -->

    <logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG" />
    <wire-tap channel = "logger" />

    <gateway id="clientPositionsGateway"
         service-interface="com.example.ClientPositionsGateway">
        <method name="fetchClientPositions" request-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel" reply-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"/>
    </gateway>

    <channel id="clientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <splitter input-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel"
            output-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <channel id = "singleClientPositionsRequestChannel" />

    <transformer
        input-channel="singleClientPositionsRequestChannel"
        output-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel"
        ref="dmPosBaseTransQueryTransformer" />

    <channel id = "dmQueryRequestChannel">
        <dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
    </channel>

    <ip:tcp-connection-factory id="csClient" 
           type="client" 
           host="hostserver"
           port="22010"
           single-use="true"
           deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
           />

    <ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="dmServerGateway" 
           request-channel="dmQueryRequestChannel" 
           reply-channel="dmQueryResponseChannel"
           connection-factory="csClient"  />

    <channel id="dmQueryResponseChannel">
        <dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
    </channel>

    <channel id="serverBytes2StringChannel" />

    <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="com.example.DMQueryResponseSerializer"/>
    <bean id="dmPosBaseTransQueryTransformer" class="com.example.DMPOSBaseTransQueryTransformer"/> 
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: This has successfully run :) Many thanks to you guys Gary and Artem :)

Comment: Just want to know parallel processing of millions of messages can be achieved with this configuration ?

Comment: Glad to head that you ubderstood the gateway concept ;-)! Regarding parallelism: do you really sure that your environment might support million threads? ;-) Or in other words: does your machine have million CPU cores?

Comment: Sorry I dint mean millions of threads. Just want to ask if this design is suitable to use in case of millions of request messages, each request getting large data.

Answer (score 0):

If your **clientPositionsGateway** is invoked from client threads, there is no reason to use executor channels. If you do million loop **clientPositionsGateway** try to use Future gateway: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway and again: without executor channels. And I don't see reason to use  `reply-channel` on both gateways.
And one more: you have `<splitter>` before `<tcp:outbound-gateway>`, but where is an `<aggregator>` after `<tcp:outbound-gateway>`?..
In your current case you get reply from your **clientPositionsGateway**, all others will be dropped, because **TemporaryReplyChannel** will be already closed.

Comment: when using async gateway, I am getting exception Dispatcher has no subscribers on request channel, even request channel is configured with gateway. Reason for not using aggregator is, I get a collection of clients, which I split and pass to transformer which in turn uses each client to build query/message to be sent to server. And each message has separate reply. So basically I want response based on query on a single client.

Comment: Also, gateway is not being invoked from threads. I load collection, split each client, make a query and pass to server. So I want each of the query to run in parallel fashion. thats definitely depends on number of threads

Comment: need your opinion on above scenario and the exception getting

Comment: 1. Do you really need sync request/reply for your scenarion? 2. To run in parallel it's just enough split your collection and put results to executor channel. 3. If you need complex result for all items you need to place  an <aggregator> after `<tcp:outbound-gateway>`. 4. To handle exception you need an error-channel, e.g. in the message header via `<header-enricher>`for each item

Comment: Yes, I do require parallel processing and thats why using executor channel.

Comment: I have another query, while processing reply message, can I send another message to same server from my service class. Ive added another method in gateway     <int:gateway id="clientPositionsGateway" service-interface="com.msdw.pwm.gim2.positions.ClientPositionsGateway">
        <int:method name="fetchClientPositions" request-channel="clientPositionsRequestChannel" />
        <int:method name="getSecurityData" request-channel="securityDataRequestChannel" />
    </int:gateway>     . Then I try to route "securityDataRequestChannel" to original request channel defined in outbound gateway

Comment: Also I tried to configure another outbound gateway for this request, but getting "No Request channel available. Cannot send request message".         What should be configuration to handle such a scenario. kindly help !

Comment: Artem @, can you suggest on above scenario ?

Comment: Don't worry: I remember you. But I don't know when I come back to you. This week exactly!

Comment: Thank you much for still remembering while working with loads of stuffs. :) Its a bit urgent and I try with many config changes, but nothings working. Is it feasible to do like this ?